# I create a repository with tortoise svn in my local system, can I create more than one project under the repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to manage and maintain my code in my local system without a Subversion server, so I choose TortoiseSVN.

As the title reads, can't a repository hold more than one project when using TortoiseSVN only to manage my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a repository can easily hold more than one project. In fact, the number of projects in a repository is unlimited. What's the question?